# Ubuntu 12.04 and Virgin Media Backup & Storage

Tags: 12.04, wine, backup

Does anyone know how to get Virgin Media's (UK) Backup & Storage application to work (via Wine) in ubuntu 12.04?

I had it working perfectly well in Ubuntu 11.10 but since upgrading to 12.04 the app keeps saying that there's no internet connection when I try and sign in to the Backup & Storage App.

Can't understand why it worked in 11.10 and won't in 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same problem and a bit of Googling turned up this: [What is the 'ptrace_scope' workaround for Wine programs and are there any risks?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146160/any-danger-in-using-the-wine-workaround-in-12-04)  which suggests setting ptrace to 0

```
echo 0|sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

I tried this to see if it had any impact and now the Virgin Media application connects and does the backup.  I have no idea about what ptrace is but it seemed to fix it!

Comment: Thank you for your reply - Sorry I haven't said so earlier, only just come back from holiday - I will try this solution shortly.

Comment: I've found that this worked :

Comment: sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip /usr/bin/wineserver
sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip /usr/bin/wine-preloader