# 14.04, LD_LIBRARY_PATH fails after setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip?

Tags: wine

`wine notepad` will not run, unless I do this:

```
sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip "`which wineserver`"
sudo setcap cap_sys_ptrace=eip "`which wine-preloader`"
```

after that I get this error:

> /home/myUser/wine1.7.19/usr/bin/wine: error while loading shared
>   libraries: libwine.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file
>   or directory

`$ ldd $(which wine)`:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf772b000)
    libwine.so.1 => /home/myUser/wine1.7.19/usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwine.so.1 (0xf7550000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7530000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7528000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7378000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7708000)
```

It finds `libwine.so.1` because `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is set properly, unless the capability is set, the lib is still found! but I get that error message...

There is this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153970/46437), but I dont want to use `ldconfig` as my wine versions are at user home, and chown to a normal user.

I dont want either to set the whole system with `/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`.

Is there any workaround for that? I'd like to know why `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` fails too if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is actually what I thought I would be forced to do (to use `ldconfig`), but I think it is much better this way:

install all separate versions of wine somewhere you understand it is ok to `chown root:root`; you may prefer to use may be `/opt/Wine`? I just put it all at `/Wine` tho (just make it sure, all its folder tree, from parentest to ./Wine is `root:root`)

then you just `chown root:root` and follow that [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153970/46437) (that modifies ptrace_scope and use ldconfig at the end) instructions and it will work fine and I understand it will remain secure

Comment: Could you clarify this a bit? And maybe you could accept it if you fixed your problem, so the question isn't "unanswered any more"

Comment: @Zanna I changed the way I use wine, now I use only the system one, so just one version of it. As I remember, ptrace is required by some windows applications. While having many versions of wine, by setting them all to `root:root` would be a safe option to allow ptrace on them as it does unsafe things to other processes. Ok I will accept it. If you think it could be more clarified say so, if you are having some specific problem say what it is, I will see if it fits on what I tried to describe and so I can also understand better where to clarify.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for responding! The comment helped. What is unclear to me personally is which part of that answer you used, did you use `ldconfig` after all? I ran out of votes today and I'm going to bed, but I'll upvote tomorrow if I can understand clearly!

Comment: @Zanna yes, I think you are right, the only think I can have done at that time ago, considering I ensured all wine was `root:root`, was to use `ldconfig` indeed! because the remainder of that answer I already new here. I will update here to consider ldconfig.