# Error in POL while installing a game

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I've  installed Play On Linux and was trying to install a game along with some libs and this error popped up while installing Microsoft NET Framework 2.0 if I'm not mistaken.. telling to change this line content from `1` to `0`:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

I tried changing it with `gedit` or whatever but it just won't save it. What is this line standing for? And is it safe to change it and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need sudo permission to edit that file.

Try this instead:

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

To verify the change, run the following command:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

It should reply

```
0
```

[see here for some related info](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146160/what-is-the-ptrace-scope-workaround-for-wine-programs-and-are-there-any-risks)

Comment: hm it actually works I tried to edit some other way indeed :) also can you tell what permission that line stands for?

Comment: @joker you have super user permission when you execute a command with `sudo`. For example, you could have ran this command earlier and would have had the permission necessary to save the file: `sudo gedit /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope`

Comment: @joker as far as the 0 is concerned, I don't know, I just noticed you needed to use `sudo` to edit that file and echo sudo tee is an easy way to do that.

Comment: thanks your example worked but for some reason when I launch it with `sudo gedit /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` via GUI for some reason it didn't work.

Comment: @JoKeR 
actually, try this instead: `sudo -i gedit /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` edit the file to say `0`, save the file and then close gedit. Run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope` to verify the output is `0`.